# Random.choice(seq), update a list

Tags: python, list, random

I'm making black jack, but im very fresh and green in programming, i made a list with 312 cards and when i make random choice of 2 cards, how to make to update list to 312 cards - 2 chosen cards?

```
cards=["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", (......etc........>>>>>)", "K"]
print("Available cards",(len(cards)))
play=random.choice(cards)
play1=random.choice(cards)
start=input()
if start=="play":
    print((play),(play1))
```

Maybe is possible some way raplace like a cards=cards-play-play1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply pop the chosen cards:

```
play = cards.pop(random.randrange(len(cards)))
play1 = cards.pop(random.randrange(len(cards)))
```

**EDIT:** Here is the code I used to time the difference:

```
import random
from time import time

t = time()
for x in range(1000000):
    cards = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"] * 24
    random.shuffle(cards)
    play, play1, dealer, *cards = cards
print(time() - t)


t = time()
for x in range(1000000):
    cards = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"] * 24
    play = cards.pop(random.randrange(len(cards)))
    play1 = cards.pop(random.randrange(len(cards)))
    dealer = cards.pop(random.randrange(len(cards)))
print(time() - t)
```

Comment: Simply and understood by me thank you, truly i dont know exactly how is mechanism of working the first answer but this way seems perfect for the case

Comment: Not only is a simpler solution, but also is much more efficient. Shuffling and unpacking a large list is quite expensive. Picking 3 cards from a list of 312 cards 1 million times took `219.76528525352478` seconds using Andrej Kesely's answer, while popping 3 cards out of a list of 312 cards 1 million times using this answer took `4.770182847976685` seconds making this answer ~46 times faster.

Comment: Curious, how u can check how much times requires any solution?

Comment: You can use the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module, or simply save the time before and after for comparison. I've edited my answer providing the code I used to time both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and then unpack to `play`, `play1` and `cards` variables:

```
import random

cards = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "K"]

print("Available cards", len(cards))

random.shuffle(cards)
play, play1, dealer, *cards = cards

start=input()

if start == "play":
    print('My cards:', play, play1)
    print('Dealer:', dealer)
    print("Available cards", len(cards))
```

Prints (for example):

```
Available cards 23
play
My cards: A 7
Dealer: 10
Available cards 20
```

Comment: Thank you it is working well, one more question about solution, i wanna edit and instead of play, play1, *cards=cards make a play,play1,dealer,*cards=cards it return error i solve it by made another random.shuffle(cards) and dealer, *cards=cards. Could you explain why in 1st case program return error?

Comment: @Jacob-random What error it returned? I edited my answer and added the `dealer` variable.

Comment: File "D:/Python/projekty/1/start.py", line 5
    play, play1, dealer *cards = cards
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Comment: @Jacob-random You are missing `,` between `dealer` and `*cards`. It should be `play, play1, dealer, *cards = cards`